# NetBeans - Trying Subversion for the first time, SVN Command Failed

Tags: svn, netbeans

I just bought a new MacBook Pro today, and started getting it set-up with the apps I needed. I installed NetBeans, JDK, Homebrew and their Subversion client. However, when I open NetBeans it is still giving me the error 'SVN Command Failed'.

I feel like I've tried everything. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling subversion, I've tried having it pull Xcode's subversion. I repeatedly enter the correct path by hand or by going into the folders manually and selecting the path that way. I've linked the Java bindings into the extensions folder.

I have no idea what the problem is - this is a brand-new MacBook. I am also super new to programming, so I could be missing something obvious. Am I missing something? My school has a repository set up and everything, I just need the subversion to work in NetBeans. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to ensure that your IDE is compatible with your Subversion client. Java apps often use a Java-powered Subversion library that is not always up to date.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That wasn't it (I know it's compatible), but after googling more on that I actually did find the answer, so thanks! Homebrew must have provided me with the incorrect svn path, so I had to enter which svn in the Terminal and it provided me with the path I needed.